# R/Rstudio stop working after loading Rcmdr package

Tags: r

I got this problem after installing the new version of Rstudio/R , I had R version 3.6 and Rstudio 1.2.xx and after update I got this .T hen I tried doing a clean install , and reinstalling the packages I had , the installation went fine but I got this problem. Anyone has an idea? I tried looking on the net but didn't find a solution.

[image: This is the build log after I try loading Rcmdr package]

[image: It freezes for a little while and then I get that error message]

Note that It's the same either for Rstudio or Rgui , I end up with either this message error or gui closes (Rgui case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on Windows?  If so this is a *known* issue and why R 4.0.1 will be replaced by R 4.0.2 on Monday (i.e. in three days).

There should also be a R 4.0.1.patched binary at CRAN which would help you now too.  You can try [this page with its '4.0.2 release candidate'](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html).

Comment: Hi , yes I am on windows , sadly I need a quick fix , i'll be thankful if you can link me that patch please? I updated while working on a project because I couldn't use a package with the old version .

Comment: It is not an old version.  The '4.0.2 release candidate' I point you at is *newer* than what you are running now because it has the fix, and you don't.  As for your question for a "patch": please look in the source SVN for R or its GitHub mirror.  Even when you have it, _you still need to rebuild from source_.  So again, your best bet is to follow the link and install the update binary.

Comment: Yes thank you , at first you didn't put the link that's why I asked. As for that old version, I meant I changed from 3.6 to 4.0.1 because I couldn't use "psych" package there. Now I installed 4.0.2 , "Rcmdr" is working thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and glad to hear it worked as intended!